# Python 3.4 multi threading and passing a variable

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-3.4

So I've never been really good with multi threading and today I'm bumping into a problem I've been trying to dodge for quite some time.

I want to pass a variable to a function that I execute in multiple threads but I have no clue how to do that in a functional manner.

Here is what I made :

```
       # This is the thread starter
    a = 0
    while a < threads :
        a +=1
        print("[" + str(a) + "/" + str(threads)+ "] Thread started")
        thread = myThread(payload=payload) # payload is the variable I'd like to pass
        thread.start()
```

And this is the class :

```
 class myThread (threading.Thread):
 def __init__(self):
     threading.Thread.__init__(self)
 def run (self, payload) :
     Checker(payload)
```

And this is the error I'm getting :

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'payload'
```

I'd be glad if someone couldn't enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=your_function, args=function_args).start()`

Comment: You need to put payload in the init: `def __init__(self, payload):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read more about the `Classes` in python.

You forgot to define the `payload` parameter in the constructor of your `Thread` implementation.
It's just simple as this:

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, payload):  # you have to define the constructor parameter here
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.payload = payload
    def run (self):
        Checker(self.payload)
```

And if you do not need some extra stuff in your own `Thread` implementation you could simply do this:

```
a = 0
while a < threads:
    a +=1
    print("[{0!s}/{1!s}] Thread started".format(a, threads))
    thread = Thread(target=Checker, args=(payload,))
    thread.start()
```

Comment: That should be `args=(payload,)`, parens around a single item just group, you need a trailing comma to make it a proper `tuple` of arguments.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! And you're definitely right I'll take a deeper look at how classes work. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @tazetotero do not forget the trailing comma ;-) - i edited the post as ShadowRanger mentioned

Answer (score 1):

TryToSolveItSimple's answer is correct, but it's worth noting that this is a very common pattern for which there is already a primitive:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from contextlib import closing

def Checker(a):
    print(a)

threads = 4
with closing(ThreadPool(threads)) as pool:
    pool.map(Checker, range(threads))
```

This will print the numbers 0 to 3 in parallel.

The `with closing` part isn't strictly necessary for this to work, but like a file, a pool should be closed when you're done with it.

Comment: In Python 3.3 and higher (and the OP's title says it's 3.4, so this applies), you can skip the `closing`, while still using the `with` statement, just `with ThreadPool(threads) as pool:`; [Pools support context manager protocol natively (calling `terminate` when the `with` block is exited)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join).

Comment: @ShadowRanger good to know, I was annoyed when I tried this in 2.7 and it wasn't there.

Comment: Thank you for the additionnal input, I must admit I'm new to multithreading, I'll make sure to take a deeper look at what's going on in your code!